# can I get the longitude and latitude of the location if the message sent is a location share message in telegram with TELETHON

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I am scraping telegram and I could get every message instance with client.iter_messages in a chat but I want to get the latitude and longitude of the location if the message instance is a location share message.

```
for message in client.iter_messages('John'):
     print(message.text)   #prints message
     ------------------    #I want the latitude and longitude of the location if the message is a location share message and not a text message
```

A little help would be appreciated,
Thank You.

Comment: FYI 'scrapping telegram' would mean you are throwing telegram away like rubbish. I think you mean __scraping__ - edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First act only when the message is a location share message ([`message.geo`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.geo)), else no need

```
location = message.geo   #returns a GeoPoint object if the message is a location share message else returns None
if location is not None:
     longitude = location.long
     latitude = location.lat
     print(longitude, latitude)
```